# How to use or load a xxx.js.twig file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, twig

I started working on a new company and they have this tool to manage different aspects of the company. They use the symfony framework in php and a jquery plugin called DataTables for displaying the tables. In the project they use a table.js.twig that is supposed to give a certain format to the tables in the whole site using the table id. my question id how to implement this kind of document. I've been looking for information about this kind of file but I only find about the html.twig.

```
the tables.js.twig:

$(function() {
    .
    .
    .
    $('#id1').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false
    });

    $('#id2').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false
    });
    .
    .
    .
});
```

the script part in the base.html.twig:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.summernote').summernote({
          height: 500,                 // set editor height

          minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
          maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor

          focus: true,                 // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote

        });
        //Here is where all the .dataTables should go.
    });

</script>
```

if i write directly in the script part all the .dataTable it works but they are a lot, and its supposed to be in a twig file to make it more readable but I don't know how that works.

This is my first question here, I'm using this as a last resource. I would be really grateful if you could help me.

**EDIT**

This is my distribution in the folders

```
/app
    /Resources
        /views
            /base.html.twig
    /src
        /Company
            /Bundle
                /OfficeBundle
                    /Resources
                        /views
                            /User
                                /allUser.html.twig **Where I display the tables
                        /Structure
                            /tables.js.twig
```

Comment: For an action, you can use any template you like : `@Template("SensioBlogBundle:Post:dataTable.js.twig")`. Where are your datatables coming from? You can then add your javascript file with a `<script src="{{path_to_your_action()}}" />`

Comment: For the database I'm using mysql. Could you explain further your answer. I'm totally new to twig and symfony, I'm currently just starting my internships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notations `$(function() {` and `$(document).ready(function() {` overlaps. So if you need to insert your table definitions in **base.html.twig**, I'd suggest remove `$(function() {` container from **tables.js.twi**g and in base.html.twig replace

```
//Here is where all the .dataTables should go.
```

part with:

```
{% include 'tables.js.twig' %}
```

tables.js.twig paths should be adjusted according to your directory structure.

Comment: This tatally looks like something that would work but when I try to do it I get the error that it is unable to find the template. my base.html.twig is in: app/Resources/views/base.html.twig>and the table.js.twig: src/Company/Bundle/OfficeBundle/Resources/views/Structure/tables.js.twigI use this to as the path '../../../src/InnoGames/Bundle/OfficeITBundle/Resources/views/Structure/tables.js.twig' I believe I had to go three directories back but it did not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please see this resource about template locations: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do :

```
class JavascriptController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * @Route(/javascript/datatable.js, name="javascript_datatable")
     * @Template("YourBundle:Javascript:dataTable.js.twig")
     */
    public function generateDataTableAction() {
      //logic to fetch your data

      return array('data' => $data);
    }

}
```

In your html you add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ path('javascript_datatable')}}" />
```

And in your Twig you can implement the logic you want to build your table

I don't know if it goes against good practices though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I the project is too bing and I would need to do this in a lot of places, I think there must be an easier way to achieve that. Still thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I used the solution from Salenix. The problem was in the path, I had to do the following in order to make the reference:

```
{% block documentReady %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% include  '@CompanyOfficeITBundle/Resources/views/Structure/tables.js.twig'%}
{% endblock documentReady %}
```

First make a block for the document ready, then do what Salenix suggested and at last I had to make the reference with the @ and the bundle.

Thanks for the help.